# OpenLayers - Event fired when layer is hidden because of zoom level

Tags: openlayers

Is there a specific event when an openlayers layer is hidden because the map view zoom level is moving out of the layer's zoom range (minZoom, maxZoom)? changed:visible is somehow not fired in that case. I can check the zoom range manually by iterating through the layers after a moveend event, but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant solution.

I'm using ol version 7.3.0.

Comment: You can call the isVisible() method https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html#isVisible